# Is Flash ExternalInterface use possible in IE9 Beta?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to get our site to work in the Internet Explorer 9 Beta, and we make extensive use of Flash ExternalInterface, using Javascript to call functions exposed by our Flash movie with ExternalInterface.addCallback.

I have seen some indication that others are having similar trouble:
 - http://www.kongregate.com/forums/7-technical-support/topics/112867-official-ie-9-bug-report-thread

I have not seen anyone discussing a workaround, and am wondering if anyone here has recommendations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

i'm also a flash / javascript / php developer and I also experienced the same problems you are describing with IE9 and ExternalInterface. The ExternalInterface works on IE6,7,8 FF, Chrome, Safari, etc. The only browser not supporting it is IE9 Beta. I really hope this will be fixed in the final version. I'm somewhat glad to see someone also struggling with this issue because I could not find much about it online

Answer (score 1):

We also had this problem and we solved it by forcing IE9 to render in IE8 mode. This is possible by adding the following meta html-header.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

Microsoft fixed the bug in the IE9 RC1 version, so we have removed the html-header and are using ExternalInterface again. This was a confirmed bug in the early releases of IE9.

Sources:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=253487 
http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2011/02/13/externalinterface-bug-in-ie-9-fixed/